# Would Bulgur be a good substitute for barley in soup?

Tags: substitutions

I would like to use Bulgur as a substitute for Barley in a Vegetable Soup Recipe. Would this be a good replacement?

Comment: What do you mean by "good"?

Comment: As far as I can remember, bulgur `cooks more soft` than barley.

Answer (score 9):

Depends on the type of bulgur, and the type of barley.

Good substitution: #4 bulgur for pearled barley

Bad substitution: #1 bulgur for raw barley

This is because large-grain bulgur is fairly similar in texture and cooking time to steamed barley.  But fine bulgur is pretty different from, say, raw barley (which needs to be soaked before cooking).

(#4 bulgur is large pieces the size of rice grains.  #1 bulgur is a fine grind, the size of bread crumbs)

Comment: +1 but bearing in mind what bulgur you (@Carolyn) have and how long it takes to cook, you might need to adjust when you put it in. The sort I have (unspecified size) cooks quicker than pearl barley

Comment: Yeah, a bit, but it shouldn't matter for soup.

Comment: Are #1 and #4 some kind of denominations for bulgur? - EDIT ah yes, they are in the US.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize those aren't used elsewhere.  Adding a note to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In a soup, anything even remotely similar is a decent substitute.
Unless you don't like bulgur, it will do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight but noticeable difference in taste between barley and bulgur.

However, do with that what suits you. You may like the flavor of bulgur *more* than the barley, or not.

The other answers do very well with summing up grind and cooking time.